# Django Rest Framework and Select Lists

Tags: html, django, forms, rest, django-rest-framework

Suppose that I have a contact form, in which one of the informations I want my users to supply is the department from a predefined list of values. Using the DRF, what is the best or the correct approach to implement such form?

Let's say I'm using Vue or Angular on the front-end. When its time to present the HTML to the user, is it better to query the back-end for the available values, or can I just hardcode the values on the HTML?

Although the second approach is the easiest, I think it is not the best, since it will be a lot of work when there's a need changing/adding/removing values from this list (assuming this same select list is used multiple times through the application).

Comment: In angular, you can use ng-init to initialize the scope variable from Django

Comment: You answered yourself already :) Putting this in the HTML is cool - till the moment you realize that the list changed :( The best way is to create an endpoint for that - and there use a predefined list (in settings or db - as you wish); The list in settings will have the following issues: each change requires to restart app; In the DB - it work in real-time, but then you need a model, an API to manage... and so on, so on.